# Chart.js: Add tooltips to table-layout legend

Tags: chart.js

I'm not sure how to get the Polar Area chart tooltips to come up when hovering over the appropriate areas of the legend. I've got the legend more heavily styled, and in a table format, so the example code I found for getting tooltips via the legend isn't quite working.

You can see it in action [here](http://trimergence.staging.wpengine.com/online-learning/self-assessments/assessment-reports/?report_id=24)

The tooltips sort of come up, but not reliably, and not when hovering over the correct parts of the table. (I also notice the tooltips seem a little finicky when hovering over the chart itself.)

Here's the code (I'm actually working it into a WP plugin, hence the js being within some php):

```
    function display_polar_chartjs_in_report(){
    global $report_data;
    $report_polar_chartjs = '<script>
                var trimergencePolarData = [
                        {
                            value: '.$report_data['subscale_3']['points'].',
                            color: "'.$report_data['subscale_3']['color'].'",
                            highlight: "'.$report_data['subscale_3']['highlight'].'",
                            label: "'.$report_data['subscale_3']['name'].'",
                            relativeLevel: "'.$report_data['subscale_3']['relative_level'].'",
                            activation: "'.$report_data['subscale_3']['level'].'"
                        },          
                        {
                            value: '.$report_data['subscale_2']['points'].',
                            color: "'.$report_data['subscale_2']['color'].'",
                            highlight: "'.$report_data['subscale_2']['highlight'].'",
                            label: "'.$report_data['subscale_2']['name'].'",
                            relativeLevel: "'.$report_data['subscale_2']['relative_level'].'",
                            activation: "'.$report_data['subscale_2']['level'].'"

                        },
                        {
                            value: '.$report_data['subscale_1']['points'].',
                            color: "'.$report_data['subscale_1']['color'].'",
                            highlight: "'.$report_data['subscale_1']['highlight'].'",
                            label: "'.$report_data['subscale_1']['name'].'",
                            relativeLevel: "'.$report_data['subscale_1']['relative_level'].'",
                            activation: "'.$report_data['subscale_1']['level'].'"

                        }
                    ];

                    window.onload = function(){
                        var ctx = document.getElementById("polar_chartjs").getContext("2d");
                        window.mytrimergencePolarArea = new Chart(ctx).trimergencePolarArea(trimergencePolarData, {
                            startAngle: 3.65,
                            responsive:true,
                            scaleOverride:true,
                            scaleSteps:9,
                            scaleStartValue:5,
                            scaleStepWidth:5,
                            animateScale : true,
                            scaleShowLabels:false,
                            segmentShowStroke : false,
                            animation : true,
                            animationSteps : 100, 
                            animateRotate : true, 
                            animateScale : true, 
                            animationEasing: "easeInBounce",
                            tooltipTemplate : "<%if (label){%><%=label%>: <%}%><%= value %> out of 50 <%=activation%>",
                            legendTemplate : "<style>ul.trimergencepolararea-legend {list-style:none;} .trimergencepolararea-legend span {height:10px; width:10px; display:inline-block; margin-right:2px; border-radius:3px;}</style><ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<segments.length; i++){%><li><span style=\"background-color:<%=segments[i].fillColor%>\"></span><%=segments[i].label%> | <%=segments[i].value%> | <%=segments[i].activation%> | <%=segments[i].relativeLevel%></li><%}%></ul>"

                    });
        var legendHolder = document.getElementById("legend");
        legendHolder.innerHTML = mytrimergencePolarArea.generateLegend();
        helpers = Chart.helpers;
        // Include a html legend template after the module doughnut itself
        helpers.each(legendHolder.firstChild.childNodes, function(legendNode, index){
            helpers.addEvent(legendNode, "mouseover", function(){
                var activeSegment = mytrimergencePolarArea.segments[index];
                activeSegment.save();
                activeSegment.fillColor = activeSegment.highlightColor;
                mytrimergencePolarArea.showTooltip([activeSegment]);
                activeSegment.restore();
            });
        });
        helpers.addEvent(legendHolder.firstChild, "mouseout", function(){
            mytrimergencePolarArea.draw();
        });
        canvas.parentNode.appendChild(legendHolder.firstChild);


                    };



            </script>
            <div id="polar_chartjs_holder" class="uk-grid"><canvas id="polar_chartjs" class="uk-width-1-1"></canvas>
            <div id="legend" class="uk-width-1-1"></div></div>';
            return $report_polar_chartjs;

}
```